# dropbox shared public link naming?

Tags: dropbox

Currently when I'm sharing files in my dropbox as a link, the links will look something like this:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/[random string folder]/[random string 1]/a.txt?dl=1

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/[random string folder]/[random string 2]/b.txt?dl=1

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/[random string folder]/[random string 3]/c.txt?dl=1
```

As I'm sharing a folder I expect the files inside to have the same link except for the last bit (a.txt, b.txt, etc.). But it seems every file gets a random string so I can't anticipate the link which is something I would need for an app to access the files.

Anyone knows whether there's a way around this? I'm only interested in public links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't predict the individual file links under a folder link unfortunately. We'll consider this a feature request though.

One (admittedly not ideal) alternative is to get individual links for all the necessary files in the first place. This of course is more to manage and doesn't work if you don't know all of the file paths/names ahead of time though.

Comment: Thanks for picking this up, it would definately be a great feature as it would easily allow apps to offer user hosted content. As dropbox is so easy to use even non-techy users could work with it.

Yeah I was hoping there was a way to avoid knowing the links ahead. One base folder link is fine, but after that I would expect to be able to access the files by their names.